# Jena TBD error "org.apache.jena.tdb.base.file.FileException: In the middle of an alloc-write"

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena

I am trying to run a query on a Jena triplestore database (TDB) that is being written to concurrently. However, I am running into an error that seems to indicate an attempt to read from the database before the in-process write is committed. I think I am using TBD's locking functionality properly, but it is possible I am not; I'm new to this framework.

The error is "org.apache.jena.tdb.base.file.FileException: In the middle of an alloc-write".

The read code is:

```
String query;
Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset("./tdb/");
List<String> outputMessageTexts = new ArrayList<>();
Model datasetModel = dataset.getDefaultModel();
dataset.begin(ReadWrite.READ);
datasetModel.enterCriticalSection(Lock.READ);
try {
        QueryExecution queryExecution = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, dataset);
        Model resultModel = queryExecution.execConstruct();
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        RDFDataMgr.write(byteArrayOutputStream, resultModel, RDFFormat.TURTLE);
        outputMessageTexts.add(new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        datasetModel.leaveCriticalSection() ;
        dataset.end();
    }
```

The write code:

```
Model model = dataset.getDefaultModel();
dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
model.enterCriticalSection(Lock.WRITE);
try {
    Reader messageReader = new StringReader(inputMessageText);
    model.read(messageReader, null, "TURTLE");
    dataset.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    model.leaveCriticalSection() ;
    dataset.end();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the write code please? Which Jena version do you use?

Comment: by the way, you can also execute the query on the dataset, no need to get the default model. this would also avoid the need for an extra lock on the model - or is there is specific reason for doing this here?

Comment: I'm using Jena 3.5.0. There's no special reason I'm using the Model class, except in order to be able to lock the read transaction (`datasetModel.enterCriticalSection(Lock.READ);`). If there's a better way of doing it, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: 1) latest version is 3.12. - please update first, some bugs w.r.t. transactions have been fixed 2) you already have a lock on the dataset. don't know why you'd need a lock on the model 3) I might be wrong

Comment: Good call on upgrading to 3.12. That fixed the problem. Also good call on getting rid of the unnecessary Model object. I'm still learning my way around the Jena API. If you want to repost your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the correct one. Thanks for the help, @AKSW!